# How can I get nativeElement of templateRef

Tags: angular

I have template that I am injecting using ngTemplateOutlet.
How can I get reference to that template in my ts file.

@ViewChild is not working, there is a 'comment' in place of nativeElement.

I got component that have input:

```
  @Input()
  template: TemplateRef<any>;
```

In the view im using :

```
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="template"></ng-container>
```

to get the inputed template.
Everything is working fine, view is created but I need to get height of element that is passed in template.
Is there a way to query for specific element ?

Comment: Can you please add relevant code to your question? That's right, `ng-template` points to `Comment` node

Comment: @yurzui I've updated my question. Basically I need height of div that I am passing in TemplateRef to child component.